# Ruby compass config file overrides

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I'm looking for a way to override the compass config.rb variables / constants by checking for a local file and including it.
Using this method (rather than the current option of defining the config file to use when calling compass) would mean we could have a set of defaults for all developers and build system and allow devs to override these if necessary for their own local setup. 
Unfortunately I don't know Ruby at all and a simple check for a file and requiring it in config.rb doesn't seem to override the original settings. My current coding attempts are below. Please could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

config.rb

```
# Compass configuration file.

# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Sass / Compass paths
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "../../web/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "../../web/images"
javascripts_dir = "javascript"
fonts_dir = "fonts"

# Output style environment can be forced on build using -e
output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# Disable the compass cache method - we use our own methods.
asset_cache_buster = :none
line_comments = false
color_output = false

preferred_syntax = :scss

# Define the location of a the compass / sass cache directory.
cache_path = "/tmp/compass-cache"

# Add shared sass path to make it easier to include assets.
add_import_path = "../shared/sass"

# TODO: Check for a local config file - use this to extend/override this config file.
$localConfig = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config.local.rb")
require $localConfig if File.exist?($localConfig) and File.file?($localConfig)
```

config.local.rb

```
# Additional custom Compass Configuration file.

# Require any additional compass plugins here.

line_comments = true

cache_path = "/Users/jwestbrook/Sites/compass-cache"

sass_options = {
    :debug_info => true,
    :sourcemap => true
}
enable_sourcemaps = true
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay @ojrask. I did figure out a solution in the end with a developer at work. However the code is so closely tided to a project it'd be painful to pick apart. However I will try to put together a simple example to show you the direction we took.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm no Ruby developer but the following should work...

The idea is we have the standard config.rb file and a config.production.rb file with all our standard production settings as a hash/associative array. We then reference these hash keys as the compass constants in config.rb.

If a developer wants to override any settings then they just add a config.development.rb file in the same location as config.rb and config.production.rb and define their overrides.

Example

**config.rb**

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Define the paths for config files.
productionSettings = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config.production.rb")
developmentSettings = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config.development.rb")

# Include the production config
require productionSettings if File.exist?(productionSettings) and File.file?(productionSettings)

# Set the compass settings to productionSettings $configSettings
compassSettings = $configSettings

# If a development config file exists include it and merge it's $configSettings
# with the current compassSettings
if File.exist?(developmentSettings) and File.file?(developmentSettings)
    require developmentSettings
    compassSettings = compassSettings.merge($configSettings)    
end

# Compass settings. If statements to prevent errors if a key doesn't exist.
# Note that any additional settings you add to production or development 
# will need to be referenced here else compass won't pick them up.

http_path = compassSettings['http_path'] if compassSettings.key?('http_path')
css_dir = compassSettings['css_dir'] if compassSettings.key?('css_dir')
sass_dir = compassSettings['sass_dir'] if compassSettings.key?('sass_dir')
images_dir = compassSettings['images_dir'] if compassSettings.key?('images_dir')
javascripts_dir = compassSettings['javascripts_dir'] if compassSettings.key?('javascripts_dir')
fonts_dir = compassSettings['fonts_dir'] if compassSettings.key?('fonts_dir')

output_style = compassSettings['output_style'] if compassSettings.key?('output_style')

relative_assets = compassSettings['relative_assets'] if compassSettings.key?('relative_assets')

line_comments = compassSettings['line_comments'] if compassSettings.key?('line_comments')
color_output = compassSettings['color_output'] if compassSettings.key?('color_output')

preferred_syntax = compassSettings['preferred_syntax'] if compassSettings.key?('preferred_syntax')
sourcemap = compassSettings['sourcemap'] if compassSettings.key?('sourcemap')

cache_path = compassSettings['cache_path'] if compassSettings.key?('cache_path')
```

**config.production.rb**

```
$configSettings = {
    'http_path' => "/",
    'css_dir' => "css",
    'sass_dir' => "sass",
    'images_dir' => "images",
    'javascripts_dir' => "scripts",
    'fonts_dir' => "fonts",
    'preferred_syntax' => :scss,
    'color_output' => false,
    'output_style' => :compressed,
    'sourcemap' => false,
}
```

**config.development.rb**

```
$configSettings = {
    'cache_path' => '/tmp/sass-cache',
    'output_style' => :expanded,
    'sourcemap' => true,
}
```